# Jquery, how to resize an Image around his center

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I am working on a web site and I would like to add simple animation effects to the image buttons.

In this case I need that the button, when clicked, becomes smaller.

The problem is that the image-button resizes itself not around its center (as I would like), but from the upper left angle of the image.

Here you have a link for better understanding:
http://www.corioki.com/pulsante.php

As you can see, clicking the image resizes the button not around its center.
What do I have to do to fix this problem?

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>resizing</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pulsante.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("jQuery is working!");
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myDiv").click(function(){
            $("#hicon").animate({height:'50%', width:'50%'});
            });
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>button</h1>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <a id="home" href="http://www.corioki.com/pulsante.php"><img id="hicon" src = "img/button_home_ita.png" /></a>
        </div>
</body>
```

Thanks to you for the attention and best regards!

Matteo

Comment: the CSS is: #myDiv {
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -25%;
}

img#hicon {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 50%;
}

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options in my opinion. You either animate the margins at the same time as the width / height with Jquery:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RdNS7/)

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
    $("#hicon").animate({height:'50%', width:'50%', 'margin-left':'25%','margin-top':'25%'});
});
```

Or you use CSS3 transition / transform:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3McxP/)

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
      $('#home').toggleClass('active');
});
```

---

```
a#home {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    display:block;
}

a#home img {
    width: 100%;
}

a#home.active {
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks 3rror404 and sergio3861 so much! It is exatly what I was looking for!!! Many many thanks, and sorry for the delay but those days I have been very busy! I really appreciate your help!!! :)
Best regards!  Matteo

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but You may consider about using CSS3 transformations and transitions. Works better and faster. It won't work perfectly but I think it may be a good chance. 
Added a class with the necessary proprieties:

```
.animated{
  transition:All 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition:All 1s ease;
  -moz-transition:All 1s ease;
  -o-transition:All 1s ease;
  transform: scale(0.5) ;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) ;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5) ;
  -o-transform: scale(0.5) ;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5) ;
}
```

Check this example

http://jsfiddle.net/EaBB3/

Good Luck